# Image not displaying in template django

Tags: python, django

I have this app in which I need to **display an image** on the html template which is not happening.

models.py

```
class cateledetails(models.Model):
    cdid=models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
    cid=models.ForeignKey(category,to_field='cid',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    elename=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    imgsrc=models.ImageField(upload_to='elements/',blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.cdid,self.elename)

    class Meta:
        db_table="cateledetails"
```

views.py

```
def mainpage(request):
    pic_details=get_object_or_404(cateledetails,pk=1)

    template=loader.get_template('student/mainpage.html')
    context={'pic_details': pic_details,}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns= [
url(r'^mainpage/$',views.mainpage ,name='mainpage'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

mainpage.html

```
{% block body %}

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>What sound does it make?</h4>
        {% for image in pic_details.imgsrc_set.all %}

        <img src="{{ image.imgsrc.url }}" alt="image">
        {% endfor %}

    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

what do I do?

Comment: what does  image in `{{ image.imgsrc.url }}` represents here, you should debug it by checking the generated value in your html

Comment: it contains the address of the image already saved in media/elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pic_details` is a `cateledetails` object.

This class has a single `ImageField` called `imgsrc`. Since `imgsrc` isn't a `ForeignKey` you can't use the `ForeignKey` `<field>_set` syntax with it. Instead, simply refer to the field directly:

```
{% block body %}
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>What sound does it make?</h4>
        <img src="{{ pic_details.imgsrc.url }}" alt="image">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @Shefali, what does "not working" mean? If you view the generated HTML, what does the `<img>` tag's `src` attribute contain? (Note that I removed the `{% for image in ... %}` loop from your original code. Make sure you do that too. A `cateledetails` object only has a single `imgsrc`; there is no need to loop.)

Comment: "not working" means that still nothing improved...<img src="{{ pic_details.imgsrc.url }}" alt="image">

Comment: @Shefali, your browser's "view source" shows `<img src="{{ pic_details.imgsrc.url }}" alt="image">`? That's very strange; how are you accessing your site? Are you using the "open file" functionality in your web browser? What is the URL shown in your address bar?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake...i had put static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in my inner folder's urls.py...it should have been put in outer folder's urls.py...its working now..thanks anyway